# Calculated Column - Add x days to created date, excluding weekends Infopath

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I created a new field in the list (calculated field of type date and time), and called it as "escalate date", then using this formula.

=IF(Weekday([Modified])>3, [Modified]+5, IF(Weekday([Modified])>1,[Modified]+3, [Modified]+4))

Say a user creates a item in a list and they have 2 (working days) to mark it as completed, The above formula calculates for 3 working days, I need for 2 working days. Please help me.

Comment: This question is better suited to [SharePoint community](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly:

a document added on monday: the due date should be set to wednesday (so tuesday and wednesday to mark as completed)

a document added on thursday: the due date should be set to monday (so friday and tuesday to mark as completed)

Then this is the correct formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([Modified])=5;[Modified]+4;IF(WEEKDAY([Modified])=6;[Modified]+4;IF(WEEKDAY([Modified])=7;[Modified]+3;IF(WEEKDAY([Modified])=1;[Modified]+2;[Modified]+2))))
```